# Dictionary from Flask is not a dictionary in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sending this value from Flask to my Frontend:

```
{1656885600: 21, 1656972000: 18, 1657058400: 18, 1657144800: 3, 1657231200: 1}
```

In my frontend, I pass it to a Component:

```
 const [amountTimeline, setAmountTimeline] = useState({});

..API Stuff (response).. {
    setAmountTimeline(response.data.search_timerange)
}

<Example props={amountTimeline}/>
```

In my Component **Example**, I am trying to access the value **amountTimeline**:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(props)) {
    console.log("key ", key);
    console.log("value ", value);
}
```

In my console, the **key** is empty and **value** is the whole object which was passed from the Backend.

[image]

How can I access the object like a dictionary?

Comment: `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(props.props))`?

Comment: I am officially stupid. thanks. I am confused, why it is props.props, but thanks

Comment: Basically you're sending a prop called `props` to the component and to access that you need to get props from the props object i.e `props.props` see this link https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component

Comment: because whatever you pass in `<Example propOne={amountTimeline} propTwo={somethng} />` is going into this big `props` object insde `Example` component. so you will have to access them as `props.propOne` and so on. or else you can destruvture the props when wrting the example component `const Example = ({propOne,propTwo}) =>`

Comment: Worth to mention is not a good idea to call your prop props, since it can cause this confusion, maybe calling it amountTimeline and then you can do props.amountTimeline will be better and easier to understand

Comment: yeah, you are right @jean182